# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express ODBC - Not showing database

Tags: odbc, sql-server-2008r2-express

Created a new database called `Test`, when I try to connect to the SQL Server database via Excel I can't see the `Test` database which was created, I can only see `master`, `msdb`, `tempdb`.

I'm running SQL Server 2008 R2 Express.

I am new to Server Management, requesting some help so I can consume the data in an Excel sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.

1. MS SQL was installed on a differnet domain and had windows authenticaion
2. When accessing from excel there was no option to choose windows authentication using a different domain.

Solution - Created a MS SQL User ID and gave access to the required database